# How to trigger status update on a schedulle

Tags: jira

I need to automatically update statuses of issues that satisfy certain conditions (e.g. some custom date field in the issue is less than 30 days to the current date) in Jira Service Desk. 
It seems like there is no suitable trigger available in the Workflow automation. 
Can someone pls advise how this could be implemented? 
We are using latest version of Jira running in a Cloud. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own postfunctions to workflow transitions (in Groovy if i'm not mistaken). For that go to your workflow, select the transition and add a custom postfunction.
A different way (that may be a bit more complicated) is to work with the Jira REST API. There is also a [jira-python lib](https://pythonhosted.org/jira/) that is using that API. 
So you could write a script that checks all your tickets using JQL and updates these tickets according to your condition.

Syntax could be like this

```
def checkIssue(issue):
  if issue.fields.status.name == "Done":
     // do something

issues = jira_connection.search_issues("updates <- 1d")
for i in issues:
  checkIssue(i)
```

Keep in mind that you can't simply set the status in the issue object, you have to make transitions according to your workflow. Could be like this:

```
jira_connection.transition_issue(issue, '212')
```

where 212 is the ID of your workflow transition.

Comment: Can you pls explain how to make this script executed on a schedule?